# Asterisk create_stasis_message Invalid magic number

Tags: c, asterisk

I stuck to send a stasis_message for a self made module to the ARI.

I try to use the code example from the documentation :

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Stasis+Message+Bus

I use asterisk 13 instead example (who use the 12), and some signature are changed.

Here is the initialisation :

```
struct stasis_topic *foo_topic;

static int load_module(void)
{
    //  Register to stasis.
    stasis_app_register(app, callback_stasis, 0);
    // Create a bridge on witch ARI can conenct.
    stasis_app_bridge_create("mixing", app, "11000");

    // Create the topic
    foo_topic = stasis_topic_create(app);
    return ast_register_application_xml(app, exec);
}
```

And the code method who is calling when phone arrive :

```
static int exec()
{
    publish_foo();
}

static void publish_foo()
{
   printf("Trace 1\n");

   char* test =  "dataToSend";
   RAII_VAR(struct stasis_message_type*, foo_type, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
   stasis_message_type_create(app, NULL, &foo_type);

   RAII_VAR(struct stasis_message *, msg, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
   printf("Trace 3\n");
   msg = stasis_message_create(type, test);

   if (!msg)
      return;

    stasis_publish(foo_topic, msg);

    printf("PASSING MESSAGE 4\n");
}
```

I always get message like :

> bad magic number 0x332065 for object 0x7f2ea5ab8ec5

And this error appends in the method stasis_create_message().

[Edit]

> *I do not understand the error and the cause any help is appreciated.*

As suggest by arheops, there is the function who are created problem. Apparently my object cannot be convert to an Asterisk object. Probably the structure I need to send to the create_message_function must be on a astobj2 type.

```
static struct astobj2 *INTERNAL_OBJ(void *user_data)
{
        struct astobj2 *p;

        if (!user_data) {
                ast_log(LOG_ERROR, "user_data is NULL\n");
                return NULL;
        }

        p = (struct astobj2 *) ((char *) user_data - sizeof(*p));
        if (AO2_MAGIC != p->priv_data.magic) {
                if (p->priv_data.magic) {
                        ast_log(LOG_ERROR, "bad magic number 0x%x for object %p\n",
                                p->priv_data.magic, user_data);
                } else {
                        ast_log(LOG_ERROR,
                                "bad magic number for object %p. Object is likely destroyed.\n",
                                user_data);
                }
                ast_assert(0);
                return NULL;
        }

        return p;
}
```

And the struct of astobj2 definition :

```
struct astobj2 
{    
   struct __priv_data priv_data;
   void *user_data[0];
};
```

I tried to create a a2object like describe [here](http://matthewjordan.net/2013/06/29/the-astobj2-library-part-i/), and I get an error :

> *** Error in `asterisk': free(): invalid pointer:

Thanks

Comment: Can suggest you search asterisk source code by "bad magic number"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send a stasis message, you need to create an a2object, normally you can perform this part with the macro  :

> RAII_VAR

But I cannot get a working example with this, so I create my-self the object with the following methods :

```
typedef struct ast_foo
{
    int n;

} ast_foo;

// Destructor is automatically called when the message is not referenced anymore.
static void foo_dtor(void *obj)
{
    struct foo *obj_foo = obj;
    // Free all resources you have reserve here.
}

/**
 * @return a ast_foo struct, with destructor setted.
 */
static struct ast_foo* make_me_a_foo(void)
{
    struct ast_foo *obj_foo;
    obj_foo = ao2_alloc(sizeof(ast_foo), foo_dtor);

    // if char* do malloc for them.
    if (!obj_foo) {
        ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "make foo failed... 2\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return obj_foo;
}
```

There is a full example for send and subscribe a stasis message :

```
static const char app[] = "StasisTest";
struct stasis_topic *foo_topic;

typedef struct ast_foo
{
    int n;

} ast_foo;

// Destructor automatically call when message is not referenced anymore.
static void foo_dtor(void *obj)
{
    struct foo *obj_foo = obj;
    // Free all resources you have reserve here.
}

/**
 * @return a ast_foo struct, with destructor setted.
 */
static struct ast_foo* make_me_a_foo(void)
{
    struct ast_foo *obj_foo;
    obj_foo = ao2_alloc(sizeof(ast_foo), foo_dtor);

    // if char* do malloc for them.
    if (!obj_foo) {
        ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "make foo failed... 2\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    return obj_foo;
}

/**
 * Send a stasis message, with the long way...
 */
static void publish_foo()
{
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Enter publish message\n");
    RAII_VAR(struct stasis_message_type*, foo_type, NULL, ao2_cleanup);

    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Create data to send\n");
    ast_foo* foo_data = make_me_a_foo();
    foo_data->n = 12;

    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Create the message to send.\n");
    stasis_message_type_create(app, NULL, &foo_type);

    if (!foo_type)
    {
        ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Oh no my type is NULL \n");
    }
    else
    {
        ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Ok foo type \n");
    }

    RAII_VAR(struct stasis_message *, msg, NULL, ao2_cleanup);
    msg = stasis_message_create(foo_type, foo_data);

    if (!msg)
    {
        ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Fail to send message\n");
        sleep(1);
        return;
    }

    stasis_publish(foo_topic, msg);
}

static int exec()
{
    // First method.
    publish_foo();

    return 0;
}

static int unload_module(void) {
    stasis_app_unregister(app);

    ao2_cleanup(foo_topic);
    foo_topic = NULL;
    return ast_unregister_application(app);
}


void bar_callback(void *data, struct stasis_subscription *sub, struct stasis_message *message)
{
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Test stasis received a message from topic\n");
}

static int load_module(void) {
    stasis_init();

    // Register.
    ast_foo* foo_data2 = make_me_a_foo();
    foo_topic = stasis_topic_create("StasisTest");
    stasis_subscribe(foo_topic, bar_callback, foo_data2);

    return ast_register_application_xml(app, exec);
}
```

But there is a really more simpler way with the send of json object tought

```
#include "asterisk.h"

ASTERISK_FILE_VERSION(__FILE__, "$Revision$")

#include "asterisk/astobj2.h"
#include "asterisk/module.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis.h"
#include "asterisk/json.h"
#include "asterisk/stasis_app.h"

#include "StasisTest.h"

#define AST_MODULE "stasis_test"

static const char app[] = "StasisTest";

static int exec()
{
    // Second simpler method.
    struct ast_json* inte = ast_json_integer_create(51);
    int result = stasis_app_send("StasisTest", inte);
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Stasis send %d\n", result);

    return 0;
}

static int unload_module(void) 
{
    stasis_app_unregister(app);
    return ast_unregister_application(app);
}

//Test stasis
void callback_stasis(void* data, const char* app_name, struct ast_json* message)
{
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Receive a stasis message from json\n");

    int json_res = ast_json_integer_get(message);
    ast_log(LOG_NOTICE, "Integer get : %d\n", json_res);
}

static int load_module(void) {
    stasis_init();
    // Register for the short way.
    stasis_app_register(app, callback_stasis, 0);

    return ast_register_application_xml(app, exec);
}

AST_MODULE_INFO(ASTERISK_GPL_KEY, 0, "The wonders of foo", .load = load_module, .unload = unload_module);
```